# Powershell : Use a Select-Object expression with a string

Tags: powershell

For some scripts, i need to have an output composed of calculated properties.

For example, for a list of ip addresses in ip.txt, i want to know if they respond to ping. So i try the following command:

```
Get-Content .\ip.txt | Select-Object $_,@{Name="ping?";Expression={Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 1}}
```

But i get an error, regardless of what i do in the scriptblock expression.

The error (in french, sorry):

`Select-Object : Paramètre Null. Le type attendu doit être l'un des suivants :  {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 37
+ Get-Content .\ip.txt | Select-Object <<<<  $_,@{Name="ping?";Expression={Test-Connection $_  -Quiet -Count 1}}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   DictionaryKeyUnknownType,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand`

I used the "calculated properties" in some scripts before, but with directories objects. Why it doesnt work with strings?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this instead, you need to create calculated properties for each value:

```
Get-Content .\ip.txt | Select-Object  @{n="Server IP";e={$_}},@{n="ping?";e={[bool](Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 1)}}
```

The problem in your code is the `$_` not the calculated property.
`Select-object` accept and array of properties, if in the array you pass `$_` isn't evaluated as a property.
If you do just `select-object $_` (as select-object -prop $null ) piped items are the output.

Comment: Thanks! I tried "select-object $_" with success too, so i believed that the problem was the calculated property for a string object.

Comment: So the gotcha here is that `{n="label"; e=$_ }` will fail but putting `$_` inside braces succeeds:  `{n="label"; e={$_ }}` ? Similarly for other expressions, `e=expression` will often fail, it has to be `e={expression}`

Comment: The docs example on the magical `@{n=;e=}` syntax for projections show but don't tell :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11-create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject