# Powershell script is missing property in result

Tags: powershell, select-object, group-object

I am not sure what is wrong with the script. I have a 3 column csv file that consists of `Name,Count,Owner`. The goal is to get the highest count of each name, then output all 3 columns, however the `Owner` column is not outputting. I am only getting `Name, Total`. I would appreciate if someone would assist in showing me what is wrong, many thanks.

```
$total = Import-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Path "file.csv"

$total = $total | Group-object -Property Name | Select Name,  @{ N = 'Total';E = {($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property count -Maximum).Maximum }},Owner
```

Contents of csv file:

```
"Name","Count","Owner"
"ctx_Prd-DG","1","User1"
"PRD-Fa","5","User2"
"ING-PROD","3","User2"
"PROD-DG03","0","User2"
"PROD-DG01","0","User2"
"PRD-2018-DG","1","User3"
"PRD-7-DG","5","User3"
"PRD-7-DG-PR15","0","User3"
"PRD-CS-DG","0","User3"
"PRD-INSIGHT-DG","0","User3"
"PRD-LIVE-DG","0","User3"
"DC01-DG","0","User4"
"Test - DG","0","User4"
"PRD-CS-DG","0","User3"
"INSIGHT-DG","0","User3"
"ctx_Prd-DG","1","User1"
"PRD-Fa","1","User2"
"ING-PROD","0","User2"
"PROD-DG03","0","User2"
"PROD-DG01","0","User2"
"PRD-2018-DG","7","User3"
"PRD-7-DG","5","User3"
"PRD-7-DG-PR15","0","User3"
"PRD-CS-DG","0","User3"
"PRD-INSIGHT-DG","0","User3"
"PRD-LIVE-DG","2","User3"
"DC01-DG","1","User4"
"Test - DG","8","User4"
"PRD-CS-DG","20","User3"
"INSIGHT-DG","0","User3"
```

Comment: Can you show us the first three or four lines of the actual input CSV file (sanitized of course)

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for responding.  I added the contents of the csv.

Comment: Try using `import-csv -header "Name","Count","Owner" -delimiter "," -path file.csv` and see if that changes anything...

Comment: please add the expected OUTPUT from your input data. that will help find where the glitch is ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `$total | Group-Object -Property Name` does not have a property "Owner"

```bsh
# `Get-Member -MemberType Properties` shows properties of an object.
$group = $total | Group-Object -Property Name
$group | Get-Member -MemberType Properties

# See how `Group-Object` groups each item,
$group[1].Group
$group[2].Group
```

So your code will be like the following

```bsh
$csv =  Import-Csv "file.csv"
$total = $csv | Group-Object -Property Name | Select Name,  @{
  N = 'Total'
  E = { ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property count -Maximum).Maximum }
}, @{
  N = 'Owner'
  E = { $_.Group.Owner[0] }
}
```

Comment: Count       NoteProperty System.Double Count=3                
Name        NoteProperty System.String Name=Prd-DG
Owner       NoteProperty System.String Owner=User1

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered this option?

```
$total = Import-Csv -Path file.csv
$grouped = $total | Group-Object -Property Name
$output = $grouped | Select-Object Name, @{ N = 'Total'; E = {$_.Count} }, @{ N='Owner'; E= {($_.Group).Owner}}
```

Regarding the "Name,Expression" syntax, here is a helpful question posted in SO.

[Select-Object expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920689/powershell-use-a-select-object-expression-with-a-string)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the suggestions, but still the Owner column is being eliminated.  It seems like this part here is removing the "Owner" column even if I specifically include it in the import and export.       @{ N = 'Total';E = {($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property count -Maximum).Maximum }}

Comment: @user12086324, I corrected the code snippet. You can try again. I realized I did not attentively read your question.

Comment: @user12086324, Can you provide an example what you mean with maximum?

Comment: I need to get the maximum for each grouped Name, this works,  But the Owner column is not exporting.....                                                                                                                                 
  $total | Group -Property Name | Select Name,  @{ N = 'Total';E = {($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property count -Maximum).Maximum } } , Owner